# How to change auto-generated comment style of Xcode 8

Tags: comments, xcode8

In Xcode 8, we can press `command+option+/` or choose "Structure" - "Add documentation" from Xcode's "Editor" menu to generate the following comments:

```
/// <#Description#>
///
/// - Parameter xxx: <#xxx description#>
/// - Returns: <#return value description#>
```

Can I change the comment style like this:

```
/**
   <#Description#>
    - Parameter opacity: <#opacity description#>
    - Returns: <#return value description#>
 */
```

Why Xcode generate the above style in Objective-C and other style in Swift ?